# MariaDB - Timeouts when lots of requests? What to do?

Tags: optimization, mariadb

I manage a poorly optimized Minecraft server linked to a database and when we have lots of players connecting, MariaDB seems to simply timeout, no CPU, RAM, or Disk overload, just MariaDB timing out on the requests.

We have the tasks limit at 15000, it's nowhere close from hitting it, `table_cache` is at 2000, `max_connections` at 32767.

And I'm pretty sure everything else is by default.
I have no idea what's up, why it happens as I'm pretty new to databases setup.

Comment: Is there some Firewall on the Machine that may be blocking the requests?

Comment: @Tony there's a firewall, fail2ban, but I checked the logs and it doesn't seem like any of those cause issues. It accepts the requests but at one point it'll timeout

Comment: How much RAM?  `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` `SHOW VARIABLES;`